# animate.css for the welcome effect on landing page

Tags: jquery, css

found this cool stuff https://github.com/daneden/animate.css. It work during the launch of the page, but after that I found the animate css still fire in the middle.

for example I use  `$('.sidebar').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');` I will still animate when I click page to page.. how to limit it only work once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to .css file (https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css) duration of animation is 1 second.

So you just need to remove setted before classes from element, after 1 sec.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.sidebar').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
}, 1000);
```

If you are using ".hinge" class, then you need increment timeout for 'setTimeout' function to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Once the effect has run then do:

```
$('.sidebar').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
```

Answer (score 0):

If clicking from page to page causes reload on your side, just don't include the

`$('.sidebar').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');`

script on sites that don't need animation.

Otherwise, use `removeClass()` to remove the class that caused animation on the sites that you don't want to have animation on:

`$('.sidebar').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');`

Comment: `removeClass()` is just a tool. Your decision is *when* to use it, as it depends on lots of things that are unknown to us ;)